# Why does my HashMap recognize hash keys that aren't supposed to be keys yet?

Tags: java, hashtable, hashmap

I'm programming the game of Othello and I am storing the possible moves found in a `HashMap` in the following way:

```
Hashmap<Matrix, PossibleMovesVector>
```

Matrix is an object which contains an `int[8][8]`, which describes the current board situation. It overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the following way. (This was necessary because the standard `hashCode()` for multidimensional arrays don't look at the contents of nested arrays.)

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(board);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Matrix other = (Matrix) obj;
    if (!Arrays.equals(board, other.board))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This seemed to work OK. But when I tested it out, and painted about 100 or so new boards on my screen, I suddenly got the following message in my console:

> Recognized hashCode xxxxxxxxxx
>   Getting moves from HashMap...

But this happens for a board which I know is new. Can it be that Othello has so many states that hashcodes repeat themselves? This is the only explanation I could find. That, or there's something wrong in my code. But I don't think that last scenario's the case, because it takes so long to go wrong.

EDIT:
This is roughly how my program works. getMoves() is a bit wordy, but all it does is: check if the board has already been checked for moves, if it's not go check the possible moves.
- Whenever a player makes a move m.board is changed. (Instead of making a whole new Matrix object.)
- boardHash contains another hash table (I would prefer a plain and simple array, though) which stores whether the possible move is for player 1 or player 2. In my previous post I didn't think this was relevant, so simplified it to a single vector.

The code, roughly, looks like this:

```
public void Init(){  
    //Initialize board  
    m_board = new Matrix(new int[8][8]);  
    m_board.Init();  
    //Compute initial possible moves  
    boardHash.put(m_board, new HashMap<Integer, Vector<Matrix>>());  
    boardHash.get(m_board).put(whosTurn, getPossibleMoves(whosTurn));  
}   

    public Vector<Matrix> getPossibleMoves(int forWho) {
        // Assign variable so the code doesn't get too cluttered
        HashMap<Integer, Vector<Matrix>> moveMap = boardHash.get(m_board);

        // Maybe moveMap doesn't even exist is our lookup table yet
        if(moveMap == null){
            System.out.println("\nNever before seen board...");
            moveMap = new HashMap<Integer, Vector<Matrix>>();
            boardHash.put(m_board, moveMap);
            moveMap.put(forWho,getPossibleMoves(forWho));
        }else{
            System.out.println("\nRecognized hashCode "+m_board.hashCode());                
            // If it does exist, maybe no possible moves are stored in it 
            if(moveMap.get(forWho)==null){  
                boardHash.put(m_board, m_board.board);
                //So then make it:
                // System.out.println("No moves for "+side+" yet...");
                Vector<Matrix> v_possMoves = new Vector<Matrix>();
                //For every empty square on the current field...
                for(int column = 0; column<8; column++){
                    for(int row = 0; row<m_board.board[column].length; row++){
                        if(m_board.board[column][row] == 0){
                            //Check if this move is valid, and if it is, return the resulting board
                            Matrix possibleMoveMatrix = new Matrix(makeLines(column,row,forWho));
                            if(possibleMoveMatrix.board != null){
                                //add it to the vector
                                v_possMoves.add(possibleMoveMatrix);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(v_possMoves.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("No possible moves for player "+forWho);
                }
                moveMap.put(forWho,v_possMoves);
            }
        }
        return moveMap.get(forWho);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Maarten! We appreciate your politeness, but introductions (and, to a lesser extent, signatures) are discouraged on this site. This is mostly because they take up a lot of space in the question previews. Also, if you indent code by four spaces, you don't have to also use backticks. Minor stuff like that aside, though, good first post!

Comment: I don't know offhand what hashing algorithm `Hashmap` uses, but simplistic hashes will be prone to collisions, as will small hash tables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: I've just thought of something which could *certainly* cause a problem. Do you ever *modify* the array in `Matrix`? You *mustn't* change the relevant values within a key after adding it to a map - it will potentially cause false positives and even false negatives (you could use the same key reference you used in `put` and not find a match with `get` if you've made a change which affects the hash code, for example).

---

It's not clear what code is printing the "Recognized hashCode" part... but it sounds like it's *assuming* hash codes are unique. **Don't do that.** They're not *supposed* to be unique. They're meant to be an indication of *possible* equality - an optimization to make finding something faster. The idea is that if you find a matching hash code, you should *always* check for "real" equality.

You haven't said what the values in your array are, but assuming they're 0 (empty) 1 (black) and 2 (white) there are *far* more possible combinations of those than a plain ol' 32-bit hash code can represent... you've got 3<sup>64</sup> possibilities, which is rather more than 2<sup>32</sup>. Now I dare say most of those aren't really feasible Othello boards, but I'd be surprised if `Arrays.deepHashCode` attempted to optimize for exactly this case, in order to provide unique hash codes for all valid Othello boards, even if that *is* possible.

As a side note, your `hashCode` method is rather more complicated than it needs to be. Try this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { 
  return Arrays.deepHashCode(board); 
}
```

Comment: To expand the concept, the contract between equals() and hashcode() is that given o1 and o2, o1.hashcode() == o2.hashcode() if and only if o1.equals(o2) is true (equals objects have the same hashcode). The reverse is not true (same hashcode does not imply equality).

Comment: Note: `new Long((long) i << 32 ^ i ^ m)` have the same hashCode() of `m` for all values of `n >= 0` (its a bit more complicate for negative values) i.e. ~4 billion Long values have the same hashCode().  ;)

Comment: @Soronthar No, it is not "if and only if" it is merely "if". o1.equals(o2) can be false even if o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode().

Comment: This is why we need down voting on comments.  Soronthar's commenent is incorrect.

Comment: @Steve: Not just downvoting, but cancelling one's upvote too. Oops :)

Comment: right, my bad. my comment is actually a contradiction: I said "if and only if" and later I said the reverse is not true. bummer. I wish I was able to edit the comment.

Comment: Yes! This is what I proposed to my peers as well, but they said: nah, it ain't no thang, the hashmap will correct for that.
What do you suppose I do? My HashMap will in theory not exceed 2^32 moves, probably store something like 1.000.000 moves. (It's used for a specific algorithm, Monte Carlo Tree Search). So what do you propose I do? Is there a failproof hashCode algorithm or should I abandon hash tables altogether?
PS: I hope compliments are not discouraged, but I really like this site. Super cool usability and the users are actually friendly, which seems to be a rarity on sites like this.

Comment: @Maarten: The HashMap will indeed deal with duplicates, but it looks like you're using hashCode *before* checking the map. Unfortunately that's in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure what you mean. 
The program does this on the initialization of boardMatrix: `boardMap.put(boardMatrix, getPossibleMoves())`
Then, whenever boardMatrix changes, it calls and checks `boardMap.get(boardMatrix)`
If that value is null, it means the board hasn't been seen before, so it does this again:
`boardMap.put(boardMatrix, getPossibleMoves())`

Then my problem is `boardMap.get(boardMatrix)` returns false positives. (Recognizing moves which haven't been seen before.)
Or do you mean something different?

Comment: @Maarten: You said that something is printing out "Recognized hashCode xxxxxxxxxx" - that's not going to be in HashMap. What *is* doing that? I wouldn't expect put/get to give you false positives. Do you have concrete examples of those positives? Eek - I've just thought of something else... editing....

Comment: @Maarten: Okay, I've edited with a potential cause of the problem at the top of the answer. If you're ever performing a *shallow* copy of the array, for example, that could cause really nasty problems. If you're able to post a simplified version of the program that demonstrates the issue, that would *really* make it easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, I should've told this beforehand. Whenever the board changes, matrix.board changes. The whole point of overriding the hashCode() for me was that I wanted the hashMap to recognize different-looking, but same object memory-wise, as being different. Else I would have to keep on making Matrix objects, and I thought that would be really inefficient.
I edited the two important methods in my original post. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Maarten: It's not really clear what you mean, given that you haven't provided any code *changing* a Matrix... but basically it sounds like you're using `HashMap` incorrectly. If you're trying to store different matrices as different keys in the map, *they need to be different objects*. Inefficient but *working* is better than efficient but broken.

Comment: As you had guessed, changing a matrix is basically:

`boardMatrix.board[column][row] = toSide;`
It's really too bad if for the hashMap to work correctly I have to make a new Matrix object every time a player makes a move, since my learning algorithm needs to run through millions of random games. Doesn't this make the garbage collector work overdrive?
But you're right about working and efficiency. I'll try making new Matrix objects for new boards then.

Comment: @Maarten: Just try to think through how the HashMap could *possibly* work when all the keys were references to the same object. You might want to create a more efficient form of map key than the complete matrix, of course... then you could reuse the Matrix itself, but create a new hash key from the "current" state when you wanted to perform a lookup (or a insertion).

Comment: Though I would like to know how this is the problem; since the hash code of a matrix, in my mind, is only affected by the contents of its array.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see your comment there. 
What do you mean by 'but create a new hash key from the "current" state when you wanted to perform a lookup (or a insertion)'? Isn't that what my overriding hashCode() method does?

Comment: @Maarten: Yes, it is... but basically each entry in the hash map is (hash code, key reference, value). When *every* entry has the same key reference, you're in a very strange state. As soon as you get a hash collision, I wouldn't be surprised for the hash map to check the specified key against the entry with that hash code *as a reference* first, which means you'll get false positives.

Comment: @Maarten: No, the hash code isn't the same as the hash key. It's just an optimization. You seem to think that the hash map throws away the key, only keeping the hash code - it doesn't, because it knows that hash codes might collide. So it keeps the key to perform an equality comparison on it, but *also* keeps the hash code so it can quickly find any *potential* matches. I think it would be worth you reading the wikipedia page on hashtables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: "It's really too bad if for the hashMap to work correctly I have to make a new Matrix object every time a player makes a move," You do not need to do that. What you can do is to remove the matrix from the map, modify it and put it back. This will allow the map to take account of the new hash value.

Comment: @David: I get the impression that Maarten wants to sort of remember the old matrix in the map as well... although it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Arrays.equals` in your implementation of `equals()` is not right. You should be using `Arrays.deepEquals`. So your implementation of equals() will end in:

`Matrix other = (Matrix) obj; 
    return Arrays.deepEquals(board, other.board);`

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Whoops, I fixed this. But the problem still persists.